# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el idioma de dotproject al Español?

Tags: php

He instalado dotproject y el lenguaje predeterminado esta en ingles quisiera cambiarlo al español e intentando de la formas recomendadas y no lo he podido hacer, ya he tratado agregando la carpeta `es` en el directorio `locales` y cambiado la variable `host locale` que estaba en `en` por `es` y el idioma sigue en inglés.

Comment: ¿Has verificado que realmente tengas los mensajes en español para mostrar en la aplicación? Parece que solo has creado la carpeta "es" y no tiene ningún contenido, por ende como no encuentra ningún mensaje para mostrar, volverá al idioma por defecto que tiene.

Comment: La carpeta ´es´ la he descargado del site oficial de dotproject llamado **dotproject_locales_sp_es.zip**´@Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: Para quienes crean que la pregunta debe ser cerrada por *no pertenecer al sitio*, por favor les pido que revisen [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan, esto lo tienes en el pdf de dotproject. Aquí está el link, http://www.faltantornillos.net/proyectos/gnu/manuales/dotProject/dotProject.pdf.
 Espero te ayude.

Comment: Para cambiar el idioma de dotProject dirigimos nuestro navegador a http://www.richy.org/dotproject_locales_sp_es.zip y descargamos el archivo “dotproject_locales_sp_es.zip” lo descomprimimos y movemos la carpeta “es” a la carpeta “locales” dentro de dotProject. Entramos como administrador, y accedemos a “System Admin”, “Configuration” y en la casilla “Host locale” cambiamos “en” por “es” y pulsamos sobre el botón “save”.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Meyado pero ya he seguido cada uno de estos pasos y no lo he podido solucionar

Comment: Lo pude solucionar agregando la carpeta **es** en la carpeta locale de dotproject tambien cambiando el valor de  la opcion **host locale** por **es** ya que esta en **en**, seguidamente de esto se debe volver a logear, y asi tendras dotproject en español.